# For comprehension not composing steps fully in unit test using Reader

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, for-comprehension, reader-monad

I have a tagless final implementation with unit test, when I run the unit test only the first step is invoked not the rest.

Here is the test target:

```
class NameThing[F[_]: Monad](implicit console: Console[F]) {

  def program: F[Unit] = for {
    _ <- console.prompt
    rawName <- console.read
    fullName = parse(rawName)
    _ <- console.display(fullName)
  } yield ()

  def parse(rawName:String):FullName = {
    val parts = rawName.split(" ")
    FullName(parts(0), parts(1))
  }
}
```

The unit test is:

```
implicit object TestConsole extends Console[Test] {
      override def prompt: Test[Unit] = {
        println("ok1")
        Reader(TestEnv => TestEnv.prompt)
      }
      override def read: Test[String] =  {
        println("ok2")
        Reader(TestEnv => TestEnv.read)
      }
      override def display(fullName: FullName): Test[Unit] = {
        println("ok3")
        Reader(TestEnv => TestEnv.display(fullName.toString))
      }
    }

    val result = new NameThing[Test]().program.run
```

I only see ok1 displayed.

Complete code here: https://bitbucket.org/jameskingconsulting/scala-effects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
new NameThing[Test]().program.run(TestEnv())
```

`new NameThing[Test]().program.run` is just a `TestEnv => Unit` (where `.run` is `Kleisli`'s `run`), you should call it on a `TestEnv` to actually *run* the program.